# C# Relay on SslStream for Encryption

Tags: c#, sslstream

Can i relay on SslStream to encrypt all my sent&received data so i don't have to hash the data or add any other encryption algorithm ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MSDN:

> Provides a stream used for client-server communication that uses the
>   Secure Socket Layer (SSL) security protocol to authenticate the server
>   and optionally the client.

So, on the surface, SSL's function is to provide an encrypted tunnel between client and server.  When properly implemented, SSL is considered to be "secure enough" for most operations.  This means that you should not need an additional layer of security.  However, it also depends upon your application.

I would also like to address another part of your question.  "So I don't have to hash the data" - if you hash the data, you are not encrypting it.  You are performing a one-way operation that essentially destroys the original data when you send it.  Hashes are typically used to see if two or more pieces of data are the same; they cannot be used for symmetric encryption/decryption.

Comment: Ok so can i use DH Key Exchange along with SslStream to provide more security ? or it is not necessary

Comment: SSL uses public/private key encryption, so that will not necessarily provide more security.